# How to pass a variable args="foo bar=\"baz qux\"" as exactly *2* arguments?

Tags: bash, arguments, quoting, variable-expansion

Take the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function print_args() {
    arg_index=1
    while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
        echo "$arg_index: $1"
        arg_index=$(expr $arg_index + 1)
        shift
    done
    echo
}

echo "print_args foo bar=\"baz qux\""
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
print_args foo bar="baz qux"

args="foo bar=\"baz qux\""

echo "print_args \$args (args=\"foo bar=\\\"baz qux\\\"\")"
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
print_args $args

echo "print_args \"\$args\" (args=\"foo bar=\\\"baz qux\\\"\")"
echo "-----------------------------------------------"
print_args "$args"
```

It outputs the following:

```
print_args foo bar="baz qux"
-----------------------------------------------
1: foo
2: bar=baz qux

print_args $args (args="foo bar=\"baz qux\"")
-----------------------------------------------
1: foo
2: bar="baz
3: qux"

print_args "$args" (args="foo bar=\"baz qux\"")
-----------------------------------------------
1: foo bar="baz qux"
```

The output I want to get is the following:

```
-----------------------------------------------
1: foo
2: bar="baz qux"
```

This is the result of `print_args foo bar="baz quz"`. However, I need it to be the result of calling `print_args` with a single variable argument. I am ultimately trying to figure out how to pass multiple arguments to CMake within a shell script that is set up to run

```
cmake ${cmake_flags} ../${target}
```

Some of the options in `cmake_flags` need to be quoted because they contain spaces, but I overall want CMake to recognize multiple different options being passed to it, which doesn't happen if I quote `cmake_flags`.

Comment: Aside: `arg_index=$(expr $arg_index + 1)` is an **extremely** inefficient (and nonportable -- `$(( ))` is guaranteed to be part of any POSIX-compliant shell, whereas `expr` is a separate tool your OS may or may not provide) way to write `arg_index=$(( arg_index + 1 ))`. Also see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete re: the `function` keyword, especially when combined with `()`s.

Comment: ...as to the real question, though, [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) is very pertinent. Is there a reason you *want* that specific calling convention, or would you be willing to accept a different one that accomplished the same goal?

Comment: `print_args foo 'bar="baz qux"'`  use single quotes

Comment: @karakfa, ...you're assuming that the OP knows what they're doing. If they want an equivalent to `cmake foo bar="baz qux"` (in which context the quotes are syntactic rather than literal, and the actual string for the last argument is `bar=baz qux` after the shell has performed quote removal and put it on `cmake`'s argument vector), those literal quotes would be quite undesired.

Comment: @Jon McClung, ...so, if you run `cmake foo bar="baz qux"` in a POSIX-compliant shell, as far as `cmake` can tell it got the argument vector (in C syntax) `char[][]{"cmake", "foo", "bar=baz qux", NULL}`. There are no literal quotes in that at all; the quotes in your original shell command were just instructions to the shell about how *the shell* should parse the enclosed substring into a literal C string, not instructions to `cmake`.

Comment: Yes, right.  I just answered the narrow question disregarding what OP really needs.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for helping me improve! Hopefully I'll be able to use this method to solve my real problem. I can't help but smile at "...you're assuming that the OP knows what they're doing." That's never a safe assumption, is it? ;)

Comment: One thing that helps re: figuring out what's going on under the hood is running `set -x` to enable logging; that will print commands as the shell sees them before they're run, so if you run `cmake foo bar="baz qux"` the log might be something like `cmake foo 'bar=baz qux'`.

Comment: One warning about `set -x`: it prints something *equivalent* to the command being executed, but not necessarily what you'd expect. For instance, the commands `somecmd 'quote: "'`, `somecmd "quote: \""`, `somecmd $'quote: "'`, and `somecmd quote:\ \"` are all equivalent (i.e. they do exactly the same thing), so the shell will print the same thing for all of them, no matter which you actually entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array syntax instead, as follows:

```
cmake_flags=( foo bar="baz qux" )

cmake "${cmake_flags[@]}"
```